# Uniqueness of a nearest point, don't understand step of the proof

Tags: inequality, optimization, convex-analysis

In proving the uniqueness of a nearest point.
Specifically:

[image]

I am having trouble with the last step of the first direction.

[image: Taken from https://www.tutorialspoint.com/convex_optimization/convex_optimization_closest_point_theorem.htm]

Why does $\lambda ^ 2 || x - \hat x || ^ 2$ vanish here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x \in S, y \not\in S$, and $\hat x \in S$ be a point 
with minimal distance from $y$.

For all $\lambda \in (0, 1)$ the following is true:
$$
 \lambda x + (1 - \lambda) \hat x \in S \\
 \Longrightarrow \quad
 \Vert y - x - (1 - \lambda) \hat x \Vert^2 \ge \Vert y - \hat x \Vert^2 \\
  \Longrightarrow \quad
  2 \lambda (y - \hat x)^T (x - \hat x) \le \lambda^2 \Vert x - \hat x \Vert^2 \\
  \Longrightarrow \quad
2  (y - \hat x)^T (x - \hat x) \le \lambda \Vert x - \hat x \Vert^2 \, .
$$

The left-hand side of the last inequality does not depend on $\lambda$, and $\lambda$ can be arbitrarily close to zero, therefore it follows that
$$
2  (y - \hat x)^T (x - \hat x) \le 0 \, .
$$

Comment: But $(0,1)$ is not the same as a single arbitrary value close to $0$. Why can we neglect all other $\lambda$?

Comment: @jaslibra: If a number $x$ satisfies $x < \varepsilon$ for *all* $\varepsilon > 0$ then $x$ must be $\le 0$. – You can also think of it as taking the limit for $\lambda \to 0$ in the inequality, if you prefer.

Comment: Oh and this is strictly because LHS does not depend on $\lambda$. But the trouble i'm having is that each $\lambda$ represents a different point in the convex set... Is it the last step which shows that of dividing through by $\lambda$ which shows that there actually is no dependence on the specific point, showing that its true for all $\lambda$?

Comment: @jaslibra: I have added more details, perhaps that helps.